# The validity of $\sup(A\cup B)=\sup\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}$, i.e. which $\sup$'s need to exist

Tags: order-theory, supremum-and-infimum

Consider some ordered set $(X,\leq)$ and bounded subsets $A,B\subseteq X$.
It is to show that "$\sup(A\cup B)=\sup\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}$, provided the relevant suprema exist". I have no problem in showing the statement, but what's the smallest number of $\sup$'s we have to assume existence of?

Does existence of any of the involved $\sup$'s imply existence of another one?

Comment: @ArnaudD. It's not a duplicate. OP is asking something different.

Comment: @5xum You're right, I should have looked better. Sorry about that (I've retracted my vote).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$, since $\sup(A\cup B)\geq \sup(A)$ and $\sup(A\cup B)\geq \sup(B)$, the existence of $\sup(A\cup B)$ implies the existence of the other two.

Outside $\mathbb R$, we can't even be sure of that, since taking $B=\{2\}$ and $A=\{q| q^2<2\}$ both as subsets of $\mathbb Q$ means that $\sup(A\cup B)=2$ however $\sup(A)$ does not exist.

Also, no other implications like this (where one supremum implies another) exist, since you can have $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\mathbb R$, in which case $\sup(A)$ exists, but $\sup(A\cup B)$ does not.

Comment: Boundedness does not imply existence of a supremum to me? Is it in fact the case? If not, what is your argument?

Comment: @Ramen: Consider $X=\mathbb Q$, $A=\{x\in\mathbb Q|x^2<2\}$. Then $A$ is bounded, but has no supremum in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, thank you. So, do I have to assume existence of all the involved suprema?

Comment: @Ramen: Assuming a totally ordered set is meant: If both $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ exist, then the right hand side obviously exists. In that case, it is not hard to prove that it is the supremum of $A\cup B$ which therefore also exists. For general partially ordered sets, not even the supremum of two values might exist.

Comment: Oh, and I just notice: Of course the existence of $\sup\{\sup A,\sup B\}$ implies both the existence of $\sup A$ and $\sup B$ as the supremum of non-existing values obviously does not exist.

Comment: @Ramen You are correct, I was (I don't know why) assuming that we are working in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Thanks, @celtschk that did help. This answer + your comments do cover all the cases, i.e. the only (non-trivial) case where we have existence of all $\sup$'s is the case of $\sup\{\sup(A),\sup(B)\}$ being existent.